# How to iterate through ArrayList<Double> values of HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

A question from a total newbie. Sorry.

I have this `customersOrders` `HashMap` that takes `String` as keys and `ArrayList<Double>` as values. I need to find the total sum of orders for each customer and the maximum total sum in order to find the biggest customer. How do I manage to do that using just nested `For` loops and `HashMap` methods? I'm totally stuck on that.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> customersOrders;

        customersOrders = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Double> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(55.50);
        orders.add(78.30);
        orders.add(124.75);
        customersOrders.put("John", orders);

        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(28.35);
        orders.add(37.40);
        customersOrders.put("Helen", orders);

        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(150.10);
        customersOrders.put("Thomas", orders);

        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(230.45);
        orders.add(347.20);
        customersOrders.put("Robert", orders);

        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(530.25);
        orders.add(325.40);
        orders.add(11550.70);
        orders.add(2480.65);
        customersOrders.put("Jennifer", orders);

        System.out.println(customersOrders);

    }
}
```

So far I've been trying to do something like this but obviously with no success:

```
double maxOrder = 0;
String customerName = "";

for (ArrayList<Double> orders : customersOrders.values()) {
    for (double orderPrice : orders) {
        if (orderPrice > maxOrder) {
            maxOrder = orderPrice;
        }
    }
}
        
for (String name : customersOrders.keySet()) {
    if (maxOrder.equals(customersOrders.get(name))) {
        customerName = name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another `HashMap` which keeps your sums and then find the maximum of them.

First iterate through all your `HashMap` keys and find the sums for each customer like this:

```java
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> customerOrders = new HashMap<>();
// Fill your HashMap as you've done above

HashMap<String, Double> customerSums = new HashMap<>(); // The new HashMap that keeps the sums

for (String customerName : customerOrders.keySet()) // Foreach customer
{
    double currentSum = 0;
    for (Double aDouble : customerOrders.get(customerName)) 
    {
        currentSum += aDouble; // Sum the orders
    }
    
    customerSums.put(customerName, currentSum); // Put the sum in your new HashMap
    
}
```

Now finding the maximum should be very straightforward. Try to do that :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
        Map<String, Double> customersSum = new HashMap<>();
        Double maxSum = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        String customerWithMaxSum;
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Double>> entry: customersOrders.entrySet()) {
            String customerId = entry.getKey();
            List<Double> customerOrders = entry.getValue();
            
            Double customerSum = customerOrders.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).sum();
            customersSum.put(customerId, customerSum);
            
            if (customerSum > maxSum) {
                maxSum =  customerSum;
                customerWithMaxSum = customerId;
            }
        }
```

Also could use stream pi for the second part:

```
Optional<String> customerWithMaxSum = customersSum.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic code is not correct

```java
    for (double orderPrice : orders) {
        if (orderPrice > maxOrder) {
            maxOrder = orderPrice;
        }
    }
```

You are not adding the prices then comparing with `maxOrder` you instead compare each price with `maxOrder`. this is not what was required in your question.

You should do this instead

```java
    double ordersSum = 0;
    for (double orderPrice : orders) {
        ordersSum += orderPrice;
    }
    if (ordersSum > maxOrder) {
        maxOrder = ordersSum;
    }
```

and in your second for loop, you are comparing a double value with an arraylist which should result a compilation error you should compare the sum for products from each custom to `maxOrder`.

I should note here that this code is not very efficient you can instead loop on keys as you did in the second loop then calculate the sum inside of it and compare to `maxOrder` I will leave this implementation as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the values in the `orders` Map.  This doesn't tell you who that is associated with.  Instead, you could iterate over the keyset or entryset, calculate the sum for that customer, and compare this to a running maximum.  Since you specified using for-loops, the following excludes use of the Stream API.

```
String maxOrderCustomer = null;
double maxOrder = 0.0;
for (Map.EntrySet<String,List<Double>> entry : customerOrders.entrySet()) {
  Double sum = 0.0;
  for (Double order : entry.getValue();
    sum += order;
  }
  if (order > maxOrder) {
    maxOrder = order;
    maxOrderCustomer = entry.getKey();
  }
}
```

At this point, you will have the name of the customer with the largest sum and that sum value.  If you want to display the relevant list of orders, you can use the name to pull the list from the original Map.